# Any way to get the resource name of an existing AVAsset?

Tags: ios, avasset

I am interested in obtaining the resource name (aka filename) of an `AVAsset`, specifically an mp4 video. The asset was created with the resource name, I simply want to obtain that same string resource in the future when I have only the `AVAsset` instance. In this case how can I obtain `"my-video"` from the asset?

```
AVAsset(URL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("my-video", withExtension: "mp4")!)
```

I am able to obtain the asset's `title`, but this is not always the same as the resource name. And the filename is not in the asset's common metadata.

```
var title = ""
for metadataItem in asset.commonMetadata {
    if metadataItem.commonKey == "title" {
        title = metadataItem.value as! String
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `AVURLAsset`.

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"my-video" withExtension:@"mp4"];
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
NSLog(@"filename: %@", asset.URL.lastPathComponent);
```

Sorry I don't known much about Swift, it may be:

```
let url:NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("my-video", withExtension: "mp4")!
let asset:AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset.init(URL: url, options: nil)
let filename:NSString = asset.URL.lastPathComponent!
print(filename)
```

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 4

```
let assetURL = avAsset as! AVURLAsset
let name = assetURL.url.lastPathComponent
```