# AVAsset not being created properly from NSURL from Documents Directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I am saving recorded file to Documents directory and then merging audios with other audios saved in [NSBundle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbundle?language=objc). Using m4a encoding for all files.File path format is `path/to/documents/directory/filename.m4a`. File extension included.

I am creating [AVURLAsset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassettrack?changes=_3&language=objc) like this:

```
NSURL* audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath]; 
AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:audioURL];
```

Logged like this:

```
NSLog(@"filename: %@", audioAsset.URL.lastPathComponent); // filename: filename.m4a
```

But `AVURLAsset` is not readable and playable and when I get [AVAssetTrack](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassettrack?language=objc) array with function [tracksWithMediaType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avasset/1387140-trackswithmediatype?changes=_3&language=objc) like this:

```
NSArray<AVAssetTrack *>* tracks = [audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
AVAssetTrack* audioTrack = [tracks objectAtIndex:0]; //Exception occurs
```

Exception: `*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array` thrown

Because `AVAssetTrack` array is empty. Testing it on simulator with OS 10.3.1.

**Tried this according to iCreative's comment:**

```
AVMediaSelectionGroup *audioTracks = [audioAsset mediaSelectionGroupForMediaCharacteristic:AVMediaCharacteristicAudible];
NSLog(@"MediaSelectionGroup count: %lu", (unsigned long)audioTracks.options.count); //count is 0
```

Comment: Have you checked the audioURL? is it loading properly with desired file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36380679/any-way-to-get-the-resource-name-of-an-existing-avasset

Comment: Yes, Tried logging, `NSLog(@"filename: %@", audioAsset.URL.lastPathComponent);` and got file name.

Comment: Please check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36845156/ios-how-to-get-all-audio-tracks-from-a-video-file

Comment: @iCreative, updated my question according to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any issue in this code. Problem was before this function. Calling merging function before stopping the recorder. The file wasn't released from the recorder and the merger was accessing the file.